# Setter of component called twice when using slice on @Input. angular 4

Tags: angular, input, pipe, setter, getter

when i use a two way data binding on angular 4, passing an array to other component like this:

**component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    arraySend = ['send1', 'send2', 'send3', 'send4'];
}
```

**HTML**

```
<app-testing [inputArray]="arraySend"> </app-testing>
```

and receive the array like this

**testing.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-testing',
    templateUrl: './testing.component.html',
    styles: []
})
export class TestingComponent  {

    private _array: any;

    @Input()
    get inputArray(): any {
        return this._array;
    }

    set inputArray(value: any) {
        console.log(value);
        this._array = value;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <ul *ngFor="let i of inputArray ">
        <li>{{i}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

works fine, but if i add the slice Pipe on the tag app-testing like this:

```
<app-testing [inputArray]="arraySend | slice:0:1"> </app-testing>
```

the setter method in testing.component.ts is called twice, i don't wanna it's called twice

i really appreciate the help, thanks in advance

Comment: instead of pipe , try to use function [inputArray]="slice(arraySend)".

Answer (score 0):

instead of setter try like this.

```
  export class TestingComponent  {
              @Input() private inputArray:  any[] = [];
        }
```

if you want setter only than you can create function

```
<app-testing [inputArray]="slice(arraySend)"> </app-testing>

slice(arraySend){
return arraySend.slice(0,1)}
```